# Incorrectly Malloc() Three-Layer Structs?

Tags: c, dynamic, struct, malloc

I'm working on a C program (Linux, GCC) with three-layer structs:

```
typedef struct innerThing{
    int data;
} inner;

typedef struct middleThing{
    size_t elements;
    inner collection[];
} middle;

typedef struct outerThing{
    size_t outerElements;
    size_t totalElements;
    middle collection[];
} outer;
```

Using other posts on this site, I've pieced together the code that should build a 2D system of these structs.  When I malloc() the space I need then walk through it, everything looks fine:

```
int main(){
    outer* outerThing = (outer*)malloc(sizeof(outer) + (4*sizeof(middle)) * (6*sizeof(inner)) );
    outerThing->totalElements = 4 * 6;
    outerThing->outerElements = 4;

    int i, j;
    middle* ptr1;
    inner*  ptr2;

    // Have to manually set the "elements" metadata for middle structs
    for(i=0, ptr1 = outerThing->collection; i<outerThing->outerElements;  ptr1=ptr1+1, i++){
            ptr1->elements = 6;
    }

    for(i=0, ptr1=outerThing->collection;  i<outerThing->outerElements;  ptr1=ptr1+1, i++){
            for(j=0, ptr2=ptr1->collection;  j<ptr1->elements;  ptr2=ptr2+1, j++){
                    printf(".");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

    free(outerThing);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
[Linux]$ gcc -Wall threeStructs.c
[Linux]$ ./a.out
......
......
......
......
[Linux]$
```

Very encouraging... although I was expecting four columns of six stars each.  Perhaps that is the first problem.  What is driving me crazy, however, is when I modify that nested loop to inset data:

```
    for(i=0, ptr1=outerThing->collection;  i<outerThing->outerElements;  ptr1=ptr1+1, i++){
            for(j=0, ptr2=ptr1->collection;  j<ptr1->elements;  ptr2=ptr2+1, j++){
                    printf(".");
                    ptr2->data=0;      // <<< Added
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Now the behavior of the program changes.  When I rerun it, I see this:

```
[Linux]$ gcc -Wall threeStructs.c
[Linux]$ ./a.out
......



[Linux]$
```

I've stepped through this with GDB and I notice that the first inner loop runs fine.  However, the remaining inner loops never run because `ptr1->elements` is somehow being overwritten from 6 to 0.  When I set the `ptr2->data` line to 9 or 7 or i+j the program seg faults; in those cases, `ptr1->elements` is being overwritten from 0 to 12898794682.

I'm convinced that when I set data in my inner structs, it is somehow overwriting data in the middle structs.  And if I had to venture a guess, it is because my malloc() call is too primitive?  Should I malloc() for the outer struct, then the middle structs, then the inner structs in a loop?  If so, are there any dangers in doing a malloc() within a loop?  I thought that was a C coding no-no.

Thanks!
-Pete

Comment: `(4*sizeof(middle)) * (6*sizeof(inner))` should be `(4*sizeof(middle)) + (4*6*sizeof(inner))` assuming each `middle` has 6 `inners`.

Comment: @user3386109: Maybe nesting makes the problem more clear: `sizeof(outer) + (4 * (sizeof(middle) + 6 * sizeof(inner)))`.

Comment: @Olaf Yes and no. Depends on whether you get confused by all the nested parentheses :)

Comment: @user3386109: It follows a clear pattern, though, as it is exactly how 2D indexing can be emulated in a 1D array and avoids redundancy. Also this can be applied straight-forward recursively for more dimensions. (and older compilers might generate better code for this, too, but that is a soft argument). Anyway, I'm a bit baffled this works actually. I wasn't even aware you can indeed nest `struct`s with FAMs. +1 for the question for really pointing out something new (and (too) rarely used).

Comment: @ Pete Regarding the dangers of calling `malloc` in a loop. The only rule is that every `malloc` needs to be matched by a call to `free`. So the more you call `malloc` the more likely you are to miss a `free` (resulting in a memory leak).  So some people will try to lump all of the memory allocation into a single `malloc` call, to keep things simple. But there's nothing that requires you to do that as long as you can keep track of how many times you called `malloc`, and call `free` the same number of times.

Comment: @Olaf Actually, that is the answer. OP's pointer math is not taking into account the space needed for the flexible array member (FAM).

Comment: @user3386109: Feel free to answer then:-)

Comment: @user3386109 Plus he should also test return of malloc (Regarding dangerous calling of malloc in loop.)

Comment: @ShivendraMishra Yes, that's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work.  I can get it to work with just two layers of structs, but not three.

However, it occurred to me that I only had one outer struct.  So I replaced it with an array, declared in `main()`.  The semantics are a little weird, but this solution worked.  Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define NUM_SETS  10
#define NUM_LINES 20

typedef struct innerStruct {
    int data;
} inner;
typedef struct middleStruct {
    size_t elements;
    inner collection[];
} middle;

int main(){
    middle* arr[NUM_SETS];
    inner* ptr;
    int i, j;

    // set up the array
    for(i=0; i<NUM_SETS; i++){
            arr[i] = (middle*)malloc(sizeof(middle) + (NUM_LINES * sizeof(inner)) );
            arr[i]->elements = NUM_LINES;
    }

    // Test populate the array
    for(i=0; i<NUM_SETS; i++){
            for(j=0, ptr=arr[i]->collection;  j<NUM_LINES; j++, ptr=ptr+1){
                    ptr->data=i+j;    // or whatever
            }
    }

    // free everything
    for(i=0; i<NUM_SETS; i++){
            free(arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```